# Compile HTML code from server.R to ui.R in R Shiny

Tags: html, shiny

I had a question on how to compile HTML code from server.R output to ui.R.

Currently, I have a function that gives me output that's html formatted through **kable()**. I tried many different renderX and XOutput combinations but none are helping me get the desired result. Instead of producing a table, I instead get this `<table> <thead> <tr> <td>...</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>` in my Shiny app.

Any help or direction to a solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can always pass arbitrary HTML from server to UI with `renderUI` and `uiOutput`.

Comment: @Carl I tried that and I get the output above. I also tried using different renders and UI's.

Comment: Did you wrap the output in `HTML`? Otherwise it is treated as a character string

Comment: Something like `renderUI(HTML("<table>....</table>"))`?

Comment: @Carl it worked for the most part. But it doesn't evaluate my line breaks. It leaves them as <br>.

Comment: Can't help without seeing your code

Comment: @Carl This is what I get using kable() <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> V1 </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> a &lt;br /&gt; b &lt;br /&gt; c  &lt;br /&gt; -------------- &lt;br /&gt; d  &lt;br /&gt; e  &lt;br /&gt; </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: what is your kable() statement? If you're manually adding in line breaks, you'll need to have escape = FALSE.